# ReactJS how to apply a Javascript script to existing element?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In a ReactJS application, I am building a component that is based on an HTML table. I give some elements in this table an ID and have a javascript file that handles specific elements by their IDs. Linking such a script to a normal HTML page through the script tag is simple, but importing this JS script in a React application seems more difficult.

How do I do it? The javascript file is local, and I know I want to load it in my component's `componentDidMount` function because it needs to be loaded after the HTML elements have been created.

Here's an example of the Javascript file:

```
var weirdTable = weirdTable(document.getElementById('table-id2'));

function weirdTable(tableHolder) {
    // Do stuff to elements in 'tableHolder' by their ID
}
```

Do I try to add 'export' in front of `var weirdTable` and then try to use that exported variable? All I want to do is say 'apply this javascript code' right after the component is mounted

Comment: React rerenders are likely to break your code.  You should rewrite that code in React.

Comment: @SLaks you mean rewrite the `document.getElementById())` part of my code? How could I do that in React?

Comment: No; I mean rewrite all of the logic to happen in JSX & React state.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is simply export your function `export function weirdTable(tableHolder)`. Then, in your react component file, you import that function with `import { weirdTable } from "your/path/to/file/"` and you call that function in `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 0):

Like @Antoine said, you should export your `weirdTable` function from another file and import it into your component.

But, you may not want to use it on `componentDidMount`, as your app is running, state changes may occur that will result in your component re-rendering which will may undo what `weirdTable` have done to the HTML element (really depends on what is being done in the function and how it affects the DOM).
If you want to make sure that this function will be called on every re-render you could use ref:

```
render() {
  ...
  return (
    ...
    <table id="table-id2" ... ref={function(element) { weirdTable(element) }} />
    ...
  );
}
```

You could read more about ref [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). I'd suggest you go and read about it because its' functionality may be very useful depending on your use cases.